# Making default jstl import for all jsp page

Tags: jsp, jstl

May be my question is stupid as i am new to jstl. I have to create around 100 of jsp page using jstl in each of the page i have to import-

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

(Some tlds too if required)
So my question is -Is there any way to make the default environment for use of jstl so that i don't need to give **uri** in each page?
I am using NetBeans7.2.1 with tomcat 7.0.39,
jsp-2.2,
servlet-3.0 version.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import my imports in JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865930/how-to-import-my-imports-in-jsp)

Comment: @Kojotak I agreed with your link and its helpful too thanks for that but still i am looking for environment where i don't need to import anything....hope you understand me.

Comment: I don't think there is a way how to do it. The only place, where this can be possibly configured, is the web.xml. You can declare taglibs there, but without the prefix, so you cannot use them without declaring them again in taglib directive.